# Is svelte store safe?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

As it may be clear from title, I have only one simple question. Is svelte store safe?

I am using it to save user data like custom claims and if anyone could change themselves to admin, it would probably not be great.

So my question is: Is it possible for the user/hacker, to change data stored in svelte store? Should I move my sensitive data out of it?

Answer (score 6):

Svelte stores are by default fully in-memory. As far as I am aware there is no way to easily change the values in it.

Of course a savvy user could probably run some program that directly edits the memory used by the browser, but it would be far easier to spoof the outgoing requests with different claims and roles if you want to do so.

Bottom line is that you should **always** be able to check on the server if your request has been tampered with, never blindly rely on the client claiming to be who they are.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using custom claims to display UIs or element on the front-end, it should be irrelevant whether the user can edit the store or not, Even if they edited the store to view the UI, the app will still need to request data from your server in order to populate the page, in this request of course you will validate if the requesting user really have the rights to make that request and retrieve the data.